# I need to emulate a specific hardware model (memory, motherboard, processor, etc.) Is there any software for this?

Tags: hardware, virtualization, emulator

I'm looking for some software that allows me to emulate a certain hardware, brand memory, capacity, etc., since I have hibernating a system on a borrowed motherboard and then sold it. I do not know if this is possible with VirtualBox because it most likely has blue screens when trying to resume hibernation.

Any software to perform these emulations?

Comment: FYI:  The system does not hibernate on the motherboard.  Hibernation saves the current system state into a hidden file on the root of the hard drive.  Suspend-to-RAM exists but is not the same thing.

Comment: @cybernard Thanks for the clarification, but I understand how hibernation works. I refer to the motherboard because I understand that you can not resume hibernation correctly, because the motherboard is not equal to the one that was being used at the time of hibernating the system.